# Needed CSS for mobile banner portrait view

Tags: css

I am uploading 3 banners slides from my admin section thru PHP. The banner looks fine on the desktop top and mobile landscape view. But the mobile Portrait view does seems right , I would like the banner to reduce to fit in the mobile for portrait view.-site- www.shoeshineindia.com

```
<section class="section-slide">
    <div class="wrap-slick1">
        <div class="slick1">
            <div class="item-slick1" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $imagename[1];?>)">
                <div class="container h-full">
                    <div class="flex-col-l-m h-full p-t-100 p-b-30 respon5">
                        <div class="layer-slick1 animated visible-false" data-appear="fadeInDown" data-delay="0">
                            <span class="ltext-101 cl2 respon2">

                            </span>
                        </div>
```

---

CSS-used for one banner-

```
   [ Slick1 ]*/
   .wrap-slick1 {
    position: relative;
    }
   .item-slick1 {
    height: calc(100vh - 40px);
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
   }

  .rs1-slick1 .item-slick1 {
   height: calc(100vh - 84px);
    }
   .rs2-slick1 .item-slick1 {
   height: 100vh;
    }
    @media (max-width: 991px) {
   .item-slick1 {
    height: calc(100vh - 70px) !important;
    }
    }

   .arrow-slick1 {
   display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;

    top: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);

    z-index: 200;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    }
    .wrap-slick1:hover .arrow-slick1 {
     opacity: 1;
    }

   .arrow-slick1:hover {
    color: #7280e0;
    }

  .next-slick1 {
   right: 50px;
     left: auto;
    }

  .prev-slick1 {
   left: 50px;
  right: auto;
  }

  @media (max-width: 991px) {
 .next-slick1 {
 right: 15px;
  }

.prev-slick1 {
 left: 15px;
 }
 }
```

Note -

Issue here is that the banner works fine on the desktop and mobile landscape But in mobile PORTRAIT it does not. it shows just the center of the banner.Need to view the banner as it looks like in the desktop and mobile landscape.

Comment: What is your current CSS? Please provide a [MCVE] in the question itself.

Comment: I put your code into a fiddle and the image(stock from pixabay) seems to be responding correctly. Can you please detail what it is that isn't working correctly? [The Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iisrael/tgp0z5fn/4/) ` <div class="item-slick1" style="background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/02/11/10/shoes-1638873_960_720.jpg)">`

Comment: Issue here is that the banner works fine on the desktop and mobile landscape But in mobile PORTRAIT  it does not. it shows just the center of the banner.Need to view the banner as it looks like in the desktop and mobile landscape.